# Linear Regression: Extending line past data and adding a legend

Tags: python, plot

I have a code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt1
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

uH2 = 1.90866638
uHe = 3.60187307
eH2 = 213.38
eHe = 31.96

R = float(uH2*eH2)/(uHe*eHe)

C_Values = []
Delta = []
kHeST = []
J_f21 = []
data = np.genfromtxt("Lamda_HeHCL.txt", unpack=True); 
J_i1=data[1]; 
J_f1=data[2]; 
kHe=data[7]

data = np.genfromtxt("Basecol_Basic_New_1.txt", unpack=True); 
J_i2=data[0]; 
J_f2=data[1]; 
kH2=data[5]

print kHe
print kH2

kHe = map(float, kHe)
kH2 = map(float, kH2)

kHe = np.array(kHe)
kH2= np.array(kH2)

g = len(kH2)

for n in range(0,g):
    if J_f2[n] == 1:    
        Jf21 = J_f2[n]
        J_f21.append(Jf21)
        ratio = kHe[n]/kH2[n]
        C = (((math.log(float(kH2[n]),10)))-(math.log(float(kHe[n]),10)))/math.log(R,10)
        C_Values.append(C)
        St = abs(J_f1[n] - J_i1[n])
        Delta.append(St)

print C_Values
print Delta
print J_f21

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(Delta,C_Values)

for i, txt in enumerate(J_f21):
    ax.annotate(txt, (Delta[i],C_Values[i]))

plt.plot(np.unique(Delta), np.poly1d(np.polyfit(Delta, C_Values, 1))(np.unique(Delta)))

plt.plot(Delta, C_Values)

fit = np.polyfit(Delta,C_Values,1)
fit_fn = np.poly1d(fit) 
# fit_fn is now a function which takes in x and returns an estimate for y

plt.scatter(Delta,C_Values, Delta, fit_fn(Delta))
plt.xlim(0, 12)
plt.ylim(-3, 3)
```

In this code, I am trying to plot a linear regression that extends past the data and touches the x-axis. I am also trying to add a legend to the plot that shows the slope of the plot. Using the code, I was able to plot this graph.

[image]

Here is some trash data I have been using to try and extend the line and add a legend to my code.

```
x =[5,7,9,15,20]
y =[10,9,8,7,6]
```

I would also like it to be a scatter except for the linear regression line.

Comment: could you precise what pb you got with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you don't provide the data you're loading from files I was unable to test this, but off the top of my head:

To extend the line past the plot, you could turn this line

```
plt.plot(np.unique(Delta), np.poly1d(np.polyfit(Delta, C_Values, 1))(np.unique(Delta)))
```

Into something like

```
x = np.linspace(0, 12, 50) # both 0 and 12 are from visually inspecting the plot
plt.plot(x, np.poly1d(np.polyfit(Delta, C_Values, 1))(x))
```

But if you want the line extended to the x-axis,

```
polynomial = np.polyfit(Delta, C_Values, 1)
x = np.linspace(0, *np.roots(polynomial))
plt.plot(x, np.poly1d(polynomial)(x))
```

As for the scatter plot thing, it seems to me you could just remove this line:

```
plt.plot(Delta, C_Values)
```

Oh right, as for the legend, add a `label` to the plots you make, like this:

```
plt.plot(x, np.poly1d(polynomial)(x), label='Linear regression')
```

and add a call to `plt.legend()` just before `plt.show()`.

Comment: This works very well, but I am having one small problem. When I try to do label = 'y = m*x + b' it is just giving the string y = mx + b. Do you know how to get it to say numbers for exame y = 5*x + 10.

Comment: Do `label = "{}x + {}".format(m, b)`. You may need to google python numeric string formatting to get it to look nice.